# Generate 2 methods with 2 different media types using OPEN API - Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, openapi-generator

I have 2 methods in my spring boot application with same `RequestMapping` one returns `JSON` and another one `returns byte[]`

```
public class UserApiController implements UserApi

@RequestMapping(value="/getUser/{userId}",
    produces = {"application/json"},
    consumes = {"application/json"},
    method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<UserModel> getUser(@PathVariable("userId")String userId){
    //returns UserModel JSON 
    }

@RequestMapping(value="/getUser/{userId}",
    produces = {"application/pdf"},
    consumes = {"application/pdf"},
    method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getUserPDF(@PathVariable("userId")String userId){
    //returns byte[] of pdf

    }
```

I generate interfaces via `OpenApi` using `.yaml` using `openapi-generator-cli-3.3.0.jar`
When I generate the interface, my interface generates this method like this

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/getUser/{userId}",
        produces = {"application/json","application/pdf"},
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ResponseEntity<UserModel> getUser(@PathVariable("userId")String userId);
```

How can I enforce it to make 2 separate methods rather than one?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with same mappings(`/getUser/{userId}`) and same methods (`GET`). But try to put `operationId: getUserJson` and/or `operationId: getUserPdf`. Can You post Your yaml file as well?

Comment: @zolv updated it

Comment: You pasted config. I meant yaml file with Your endpoint definitions.

Comment: @zolv it's a file with 8k+ lines. Let m try to copy the methods config and see if I can generate 2 separate methods or not

Comment: I just checked with a simple test and mapping + method need to be unique. I am just surprised that it was possible to generate it without errors mentioning about duplicate mappings.

Comment: I tried, it generated one method. Can you please share your sample with me? @zolv

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/p5u6o9Lj/
I checked it on swaggerhub.com. It give error about duplicated entries.

Comment: Thanks @zolv I will try it and get back to you. Thanks once again

Answer (score 2):

According to our comments under Your post, it is not possible.

[Quote from specification](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/paths-and-operations/):

> OpenAPI defines a unique operation as a combination of a path and an HTTP method. This means that two GET or two POST methods for the same path are not allowed